# Drop duplicated rows in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am querying some data from the database, and my code looks as below

```
select 
a.id
a.party
a.date
a.name
a.revenue
b.company
c.cost 
from a
left join b on a.id = b.id
left join c on a.id = c.id
where a.party = 'cat' and a.date > '2000-01-01'
```

I got a returned table but the table has duplicated rows. Is there anyway I can remove all duplicated rows (meaning the entire row is the same, row 1 = row2, remove row1)

I put `select distinct` at the top, but then it took forever to run. Not sure if some fundamental programming logic was wrong in this code.

Comment: Possibly, a workaround is `select distinct`. But bottom line, something is probably wrong in the logic of query if you get more rows than you expect. If you were to provide a minimum reproducible example (sample data from the 3 tables, current and desired results), one might suggest improvements.

Comment: `left join b on a.id = b.id
left join c on a.id = c.id` at least one of these three tables must have duplicate `id`s. Which one(s)

Answer (score 0):

If one row in `a` id related to two rows in `b` because `b.id` is not unique, and both these rows have the same `company`, your query result will contain duplicate rows. There is nothing wrong with that.

Removing duplicate rows with `DISTINCT` is expensive for big result sets, because the set has to be sorted.

Ideas to improve performance:

- increase `work_mem`, that makes sorting faster
- perhaps you don't need all the result rows, then adding a `LIMIT` clause will make the query faster

Answer (score 0):

Normal deduplicate process with better performance is using row_number() over(partition by order by) and then rownumber =1.

```
Select a_id, b_id, name, ... 
From
( Select a.id a_id, b.id b_id, b.name name,
row_number() over (partition by a.id,b.id, b.name order by create_date desc) rownum from 
A 
Join b on a.id=b.id) rs 
Where rs.rownum=1
```

Please note you can partition by, order by any key column(whatever you want as unique). I used create date to pick latest row.
Also note huge number of row can hamper performance but it's better than distinct. Also plss check if you can get distinct first before joining.